Evaluating a rational function integral in a quick way
In an recent test I was asked to evaluate the integral
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2(1-x)}}{(1+x)^3} \text{d}x$$
in 8 minutes, but I didn't have a clue what to do with it.
After the test, I tried the following approach: substituting $x=\frac{1}{t}, u=\sqrt[3]{t-1}$ gives
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2(1-x)}}{(1+x)^3} \text{d}x=\int_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt[3]{t-1}}{(t+1)^3}\text{d}t=\int_0^\infty \frac{3u^3}{(u^3+2)^3}\text{d}u$$
then it becomes a problem of evaluating a rational function integral, but I still don't think it could be done in the time limit.

Is there any quick method to evaluate this? Thanks for any help.

(Note: 1. The integral is $\frac{\pi}{9\times 2^{2/3}\sqrt3}$ according to Wolfram Alpha.
2. It is best to solve it with first-year calculus, and I will understand more easily. Other solutions are also welcomed:)

For approaches which use some heavy machinery (complex integration, Beta functions) see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629945/evaluate-int-01-frac-sqrt4x-1-x31x3-mathrmdx?noredirect=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4171223/complex-integration-int-01-frac-sqrt34x2-left1-x-right-left1?noredirect=1

Hint: $u^3=(u^3+2)-2$  (Btw, is that from the fake TACA examination?)

Does this answer your question? Complex integration $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{4x^{2}\left(1-x\right)}}{\left(1+x\right)^{3}}dx$

@tys the first question: yes; the second question: not completely, as it uses complex integration

Substitute $x=\frac{1-t}{1+t}$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2(1-x)}}{(1+x)^3} {d} 
=\frac1{2^{5/3}}\int_0^1 (1-t)^{\frac23}t^{\frac13}dt\\
= & \ \frac{\Gamma(\frac43)\Gamma(\frac53)}{2^{8/3}}
= \frac{\Gamma(\frac13)\Gamma(\frac23)}{18\cdot 2^{2/3}}
= \frac{\pi}{9\sqrt3\cdot 2^{2/3}}
\end{align}
where the reflection formula $\Gamma(a)\Gamma(1-a)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi a)}$ is used in the last step.

This is THE way.

How did you come up with substituting $x=\frac{1-t}{1+t}$?

@Cyankite it is a well-know sub for integral bounds of $(0,1)$

@Quanto It happens that I don't know the well-known sub.... So, under what circumstances can one use it to simplify an integral?

@Cyankite It is an example of a linear fractional transformation. If your integrand is a product of linear terms raised to powers, it still will be after the transformation. The idea is to choose the four constants of the LFT so that the new integral is simpler.

Nice for advanced users. However, as OP points out, he would have liked to see a solution on first-year calculus level, and I doubt gamma functions are then part of the curriculum.

+1 Good $\mbox{}$

@Andreas It's indeed part of my curriculum:)

I'm gonna accept this answer, it's too nice:)

I added a way to solve it without Gamma functions and with only one very well-known integral. For calculus beginners (-;

@Andreas: Please don't assume that anonymous users are male.

@Cyankite It works, in this case, because the exponents -powers- in the numerator and denominator satisfy $\displaystyle\color{red}{1/3} + \color{red}{2/3} + 2 = \color{red}{3}$. In general, for an expression
$$
\propto {x^{a - 1},,\left(1 - x\right)^{b - 1} \over \left(1 + x\right)^{a + b}}
$$

I would like to start with the following intergral, as you have written:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{3u^3}{(u^3+2)^3}\text{d}u$$
Substitute $u = 2^{\frac{1}{3}}v$, and the intergral becomes:
$$ 2^{\frac{1}{3}}\times \frac{3}{4} \int_0^\infty \frac{v^3}{(v^3+1)^3}\text{d}v$$
Let
$$I_n=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x^3+1)^n}\text{d}x=-\int_0^\infty x\text{d}\frac{1}{(x^3+1)^n}=3n\int_0^\infty \frac{x^3}{(x^3+1)^{n+1}}\text{d}x=3n\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^3+1-1}{(x^3+1)^{n+1}}\text{d}x=3nI_n-3nI_{n+1}\implies I_{n+1}=\frac{3n-1}{3n}I_n.$$
As
$$I_1=\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^3+1}\text{d}x=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}},$$
we can easily know that
$$I_2-I_3=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{v^3}{(v^3+1)^3}\text{d}v=\frac{2\pi}{27\sqrt{3}}.$$
Therefore,
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2(1-x)}}{(1+x)^3} \text{d}x=2^{\frac{1}{3}}\times \frac{3}{4} \int_0^\infty \frac{v^3}{(v^3+1)^3}\text{d}v=2^{\frac{1}{3}}\times \frac{3}{4} \times \frac{2\pi}{27\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\pi}{9\times 2^{2/3}\sqrt{3}}$$
as desired.

This is the usual method that I have been reluctant to use:( Evaluating $I_1$ takes time

I like the way you developed the recursive formula for $I_n$. It's quicker than I thought

Your method depends on evaluating $I_1$ where you simply state the result. Actually doing this in a naive way (partial fractions etc.) takes considerable time. I have updated my answer to show an easy and short way to do it.

@Andreas Your method on computing $I_1$ is elegant and fast. (In China, there is a book introduced your method, so that your method is well-known. Actually Cyankite is the best student in my high school btw.)

@tys It is you I'm a noob

@tys which book? I haven't read it but you did but you keep saying I'm better than u u make fun of me every day Do u enjoy bullying me like this??
(Go WeChat for further chats.)

Here is a way without Gamma functions, and with one well-known  integral only.
Starting as @tys:
From OP
$$I = \int_0^\infty \frac{3u^3}{(u^3+2)^3}\text{d}u$$
Substituting $u = 2^{\frac{1}{3}}v$, the integral $I$ becomes:
$$ I = 2^{\frac{1}{3}}\times \frac{3}{4} \int_0^\infty \frac{v^3}{(v^3+1)^3}\text{d}v$$
What comes now is a  method of parametric integration:
Consider, with $a>0$ and $b>0$,  the more general integral:
$$ K(a,b) = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{a^3v^3+b^3}\text{d}v$$
Notice that
$$
\frac{\partial^2 K(a,b)}{\partial a  \partial b} = 
18 a^2 b^2 \int_0^\infty \frac{v^3}{(a^3v^3+b^3)^3}\text{d}v$$
hence
$$
I = 2^{\frac{1}{3}}\times \frac{3}{4\times 18} \lim_{a =1; b = 1}\frac{\partial^2 K(a,b)}{\partial a  \partial b}
$$
Now the integration in $K(a,b)$ seems complicated, but can be made astonishingly simple. All that is needed is the well-known integral
$$ \int\frac{1}{x^2 + 1 }\text{d}x = \tan^{-1}(x)$$
First, let $x = \frac a b v$ to obtain:
$$
K(a,b) = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{a^3v^3+b^3}\text{d}v = \frac1{ a b^2} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^3+1}\text{d}x$$
Then, let $t = 1/x$ which gives:
$$
K(a,b) =  \frac1{ a b^2} \int_0^\infty \frac{t}{t^3+1}\text{d}t$$
Adding the two formulations of $K(a,b)$
$$
2 K(a,b) =  \frac1{ a b^2} \int_0^\infty \frac{t+1}{t^3+1}\text{d}t
= \frac1{ a b^2} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(t-\frac 1 2)^2 + \frac 3 4 }\text{d}t = \frac{2}{a b^2\sqrt{3}} \tan^{-1}\frac{2 t - 1}{\sqrt{3}} |_{0}^{\infty}$$
Inserting the limits we have
$$
K(a,b) =   \frac{1}{a b^2\sqrt{3}} (\frac{\pi}{2}- \frac{-\pi}{6}) = \frac{2 \pi}{3 a b^2\sqrt{3}} $$
Then
$$
\frac{\partial^2 K(a,b)}{\partial a  \partial b}  = \frac{4 π}{3 \sqrt{3} a^2 b^3}
$$
and finally
$$
I = 2^{\frac{1}{3}}\times \frac{1}{24} \lim_{a =1; b = 1}\frac{\partial^2 K(a,b)}{\partial a  \partial b} = 2^{\frac{1}{3}}\times \frac{1}{24} \times \frac{4 π }{3 \sqrt{3} } =\frac{\pi}{9\times 2^{2/3}\sqrt{3}}$$
as desired.

Cool parametric integration! +1
However, it seems to make things more complicated and takes more time:)

@Cyankite I updated the integration. Apart from usual easy variable substitutions, this reduces now to a very well-known integral. So even if people have no knowledge of Gamma functions, this is now digestable and can be done in short time for  calculus beginners.

Simple but elegant:) (referring to the integration of $K(a,b)$)

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\int_{0}^{1}{\root[\large 3]{\rule{0pt}{3.85mm}x^{2}\pars{1 - x}} \over \pars{1 + x}^{3}}\dd x} \\[5mm] = & \ {1 \over 2^{5/3}}\bracks{\color{red}{1}^{4/3}\ \pars{1 + \color{red}{1}}^{\color{red}{5/3}}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{\color{red}{5/3}\ -\ 1}\,\,
\pars{1 - x}^{\color{red}{4/3}\ -\ 1}\
\over \pars{x + \color{red}{1}}^{\color{red}{5/3}\ +\ \color{red}{4/3}}}\dd x}
\\[5mm] = & \
\bbx{\color{#44f}{{1 \over 2^{5/3}}\ \on{B}\pars{{5 \over 3},{4 \over 3}}}} \approx 0.1270\\ &
\end{align}
where I used G & R $\ds{{\bf 8.380}.7}$  identity.

An elementary way to compute the "crux integral" in the solution by @tys:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^3}dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^3}dx + \underbrace{\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^3}dx}_{x\rightarrow 1/x} = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^2-x+1} = \ldots$$

This is exactly what Andreas did.

@Cyankite: Look again.

I have looked again, and I'm pretty sure your answer is identical to Andrea's Lines 18-24, which compute the integral $K(a,b)$.
